# Updating a specific XML node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am new to XML files and how to manage them. This is for a web app I am writing (aspx).

At the present time I am able to find the first instance of a node and add an item to it with the following code:

```
xmlClone.Element("PCs").Element("PC").Element("pc_hwStatus").AddAfterSelf(new XElement("user_name", txt_v0_nombre.Text));
```

What I really want is to add ("user_name", txt_v0_nombre.Text) to a node in particular, not the first one. The content of my XML file is:

```
<PCs> 
<PC> 
    <pc_name>esc01</pc_name> 
    <pc_ip>10.10.10.10</pc_ip>
    <pc_hwStatus>Working</pc_hwStatus>
 </PC> 
 <PC> 
    <pc_name>esc02</pc_name>
    <pc_ip>10.10.10.11</pc_ip> 
    <pc_hwStatus>Under Maintenance</pc_hwStatus>
 </PC>
 </PCs>
```

The decision of what node to update is made selecting an item from a dropdown list (the PC name).

With my current code, the new item is always added as last line of node with "pc_
name = esc01". I want to be able to added it to esc02 or esc03 and so on... How can this be accomplished? (Using xdocument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is the `FirstOrDefault` extension method. In there specify which node you are wanting, in this case a string from your dropdown box, which can be passed in. So to get the first node:

```
var pc = xmlClone.Element("PCs").Elements("PC").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("pc_name").Value == "esc01");
```

Now you have this in your XElement:

```
<PC> 
    <pc_name>esc01</pc_name> 
    <pc_ip>10.10.10.10</pc_ip>
    <pc_hwStatus>Working</pc_hwStatus>
</PC>
```

To get any element like that, just replace this clause:

```
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("pc_name").Value == "esc01");
```

with this one

```
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("pc_name").Value == desiredPC);
```

where `desiredPC` is the value of the xml node: `pc_name`.

Now to add your data just call the plain old `Add` method:

```
pc.Add(new XElement("user_name", txt_v0_nombre.Text);
```

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses **LINQ query syntax** with **LINQ to XML:**

```cs
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
string pcName = "esc02";

IEnumerable<XElement> query =
    from pc in document.Element("PCs").Elements("PC")
    where pc.Element("pc_name").Value.Equals(pcName)
    select pc;

XElement xe = query.FirstOrDefault();

if (xe != null)
{
    xe.Add(new XElement("user_name", "DMS"));
}
```

I have incorporated your sample data and this query into a demonstration program. Please see below for the output from the demonstration program followed by the program itself.

**Expected Output**

```xml
<PC>
  <pc_name>esc02</pc_name>
  <pc_ip>10.10.10.11</pc_ip>
  <pc_hwStatus>Under Maintenance</pc_hwStatus>
  <user_name>DMS</user_name>
</PC>
```

**Demonstration Program**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace LinqToXmlDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlContent = GetXml();
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);

            XElement xe = FindPCName(document, "esc02");

            if (xe != null)
            {
                xe.Add(new XElement("user_name", "DMS"));
                Console.WriteLine(xe);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Query returned no results.");
            }
        }

        private static XElement FindPCName(XDocument document, String pcName)
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> query =
                from pc in document.Element("PCs").Elements("PC")
                where pc.Element("pc_name").Value.Equals(pcName)
                select pc;

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private static String GetXml()
        {
            return
                @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                  <PCs> 
                    <PC> 
                      <pc_name>esc01</pc_name> 
                      <pc_ip>10.10.10.10</pc_ip>
                      <pc_hwStatus>Working</pc_hwStatus>
                    </PC> 
                    <PC> 
                      <pc_name>esc02</pc_name>
                      <pc_ip>10.10.10.11</pc_ip> 
                      <pc_hwStatus>Under Maintenance</pc_hwStatus>
                    </PC>
                  </PCs>";
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `.Element` returns the first element with the specified name.

You can get the whole list with method `.Elements`, and iterate this list to find the one you are looking for.